# Falling body with drag

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

I was doing a question and I couldn't figure out the answer, when I checked the worked solutions it did a thing and I'm not entirely sure what I am missing.

The general gist of the question is as follows:

> A particle $A$ is dropped from a high height with no initial velocity, after a time $T$ another particle, $B$, is dropped from the same height with an initial velocity $u$. We want to show that it must be true that  $T\le\frac{u}{g}$ if we want the particles to ever pass each other (that is have the same displacement).

The acceleration of both the particles is $g-kv$ for $v$ being their respective velocities.

After a bit of work I found (and the answers agree) that:

$$T=\frac{-1}{k}\ln{(\frac{g-ku}{g}\frac{g-kv_A}{g-kv_B})}$$,

$$x_A=\frac{1}{k}(-v_A+\frac{g}{k}\ln{(\frac{g}{g-kv_A})})$$

and

$$x_B=\frac{1}{k}(u-v_B+\frac{g}{k}\ln{(\frac{g-ku}{g-kv_B})})$$

After equating $x_A$ and $x_B$ and doing a bit of algerbra we get:

$$\frac{g}{k}\ln{(\frac{g-ku}{g}\frac{g-kv_A}{g-kv_B})}=v_B-v_A-u$$

Up until this point everything is fine, the problem occurs now because the answers state that “because that is true, at the point of contact:

$$\frac{-1}{k}\ln{(\frac{g-ku}{g}\frac{g-kv_A}{g-kv_B})}=\frac{u}{g}$$”

And that pretty much finishes off the worked solution.

It appears that they have equated $v_A=v_B$ and I don't understand how that could be true, it seems that if it were true the particles wouldn’t overtake each other. IDK though, maybe that’s not what the answers are doing and I'm just missing something else.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated, perhaps the answers are wrong. If what I have said isn't clear the question is "question 14 (a) (iii) of the 2020 North Sydney Boys HSC trial paper" available at https://thsconline.github.io/s/v/5348/North%20Sydney%20Boys%202020%20w.%20sol (this website takes about half a min to load but its not broken.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important fact in this excercise is that both particles experience the same drag force. It follows that they will both have the same final (maximum) velocity. When reaching this velocity they must either have already passed each other, have the same displacement or will never pass each other.
So if you set
$$
x_A = x_B
$$
and then do algebra until you reach at the equation you showed (I replaced the left side with the time T)
$$
T = \frac{-v_B + v_A + u}{g}
$$
you can see that when both particles reach their final velocity (when we know that $v_A = v_B$) the maximum allowed time between them so that there is still a solution to the equation $x_A = x_B$ is for
$$ T = \frac{u}{g}.$$

You are right that in this limit they not really "pass" each other. They only reach the same displacement and then travel on together. Only when T is smaller than u/g the one particle passes the other in the sense that $x_B > x_A$. Taking both cases together we get show the desired condition:
$$
T \leq \frac{u}{g}
$$